# How to scale a repeating pattern in SVG?

Tags: css, svg

Here is a repeating SVG pattern:

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="72">
    <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I'd like to scale the pattern down so it becomes only 24px in height (and still repeat itself the full width of the container).

How could I achieve this **without modifying the `circle`s attributes?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using only CSS:

```css
.box {
  --s:1; /* control the scale with this */
  /* Or the sizes with this*/
  --h:100px;
  --w:50px;
  /**/

  height:100px;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#000 19%,transparent 21%) 
        calc(var(--s)* (var(--w)/5 - var(--w)/2)) calc(var(--s)*(var(--h)/10 - var(--h)/2)),
    
    radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#000 19%,transparent 21%) 
        calc(var(--s)*(var(--w)/5)) 0,
 
    radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#000 19%,transparent 21%) 
        calc(var(--s)*(var(--w)/5 - var(--w)/2)) calc(var(--s)*(var(--h)/2 - var(--h)/10));
 
  background-size:calc(var(--w)*var(--s)) calc(var(--h)*var(--s));
  background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:0.8"></div>
<div class="box" style="--h:50px;--w:30px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--h:50px;--w:30px;--s:0.5"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:0.5"></div>

<div class="box" style="--s:0.2"></div>
```

With your SVG you can apply a scale transformation but make sure the rect is big enough so it always cover the whole area when scaled down:

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="72" >
    <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="72" >
    <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)" transform="scale(0.8)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="72" >
    <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
      <circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="#000"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)" transform="scale(0.5)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can also use it as background:

```css
.box {
  height: 140px;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="72" ><pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle><circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle><circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle></pattern><rect x="0" y="0" width="1000%" height="100%" fill="url(%23dots)"></rect></svg>') no-repeat,
  #ddd
}

.alt {
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="72" ><pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="42" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><circle cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle><circle cx="30.5" cy="36" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle><circle cx="9.5" cy="62.5" r="9.5" fill="black"></circle></pattern><rect x="0" y="0" width="1000%" height="100%" fill="url(%23dots)" transform="scale(0.5)"></rect></svg>') no-repeat,
  #ddd
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box alt">
</div>
```